# Why does the xmlns attribute not apply to child elements in Visual Studio's XML Editor?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd

[image: 1]

As you can see the only difference (left) besides the "non-working" and "working" version is the use of a "this" prefix everywhere.

Isn't the whole point of the default namespace `xmlns` attribute is to avoid this exact issue?

Am I doing something wrong here?

As per request here is the XSD as code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="Ember.Graphics.OpenGL"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified"

    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    
    xmlns="Ember.Graphics.OpenGL"
>
    <xsd:element name="UniformBlock">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="BlockMember" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required" type="Types"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="instanceName" use="optional" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="layout" use="optional" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:simpleType name="Types">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="mat4"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="mat3"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="vec3"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="vec4"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="float"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And the "working" XML (slightly altered):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:UniformBlock
    xmlns:x="Ember.Graphics.OpenGL"
>
    <x:BlockMember
        x:type="mat4"
        x:name="WorldToCamera"
    />
</x:UniformBlock>
```

Comment: You should post code as plain text and not as screenshots; screenshots it makes it harder for people to try to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think one mistake in your sample or your expectations is the use of attributeFormDefault="qualified" and the use of unprefixed attributes in the default namespace sample; the default namespace declaration applies to elements but not to attributes.

So depending on your needs/requirements you want to drop the `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` or you need to ensure, if you want your attributes to be in the (target) namespace, that your prefix the attribute names in your XML samples with a prefix bound to the namespace.